# Python3 <sqlite3.Row object at 0x10fcbb4b0> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

Python3.7

I have the following GET endpoint to return the data in the database, but keeps getting

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Exception in _query: <sqlite3.Row object at 0x10fcbb4b0> is not JSON serializable"
}
```

Here is the code. I have been trying many different solutions but none of them works. Any thoughts?

Any way I can printout the sqlite3 data? When I do

```
print(entries)
```

I will return

as well. Any thoughts? Thank you!

```
# all the imports
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
     render_template, flash

from .response import Response

app = Flask(__name__) # create the application instance :)
app.config.from_object(__name__) # load config from this file , flaskr.py

import json
import requests

    @app.route('/table_result', methods=['GET'])
    def table_result():

        try:

            db = get_db()

            cur = db.execute("SELECT name FROM mouse_tracking; ")

            entries = cur.fetchall()

            # return Response(200, json.dumps(entries)).payload()

            return json.dumps(entries)

        except sqlite3.Error as e:

            return Response(400, "Database error: %s" % e).payload()

        except Exception as e:

            return Response(400, "Exception in _query: %s" % e).payload()
```

Answer (score 1):

(i cant comment yet) did you use cursor?

```
    def table():
    try:
        db = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM db")
        entries = cursor.fetchall()

        return jsonify(json.dumps(entries))

    except Exception as e:
        return Response(400, "Exception: %s" % e).payload()
```

you should use db.cursor() to execute commands on the database

Comment: object of type 'Row' is not json serializable